# Trying to use a Jquery Ajax post to pull data from my URL and post it in my html Div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to pull real time data with a Jquery Ajax Post method. I only have a slight idea as to how to code in this type of language. I deal with mostly SQL and C#. I was told this is the script to use, and that it should be no problem. I thought I could do it, and research it. But every time I do, I get no other info from when I run it. I'm running it in ASP.NET and have my Jquery source connected. Or should I have the script in a seperate jquery file and link it to my html?  Any help at all would be appreciated.

Tried changing how it pulls data from URL. I tried inputting my USer and pass through HTML to pull the data straight that way. Then I tried putting them into the script itself. Didn't work.  I obviously took out the user name and password and and query ID.  The Jquery script is correct syntax from what I'm told, my results to my div is where I'm messing up.

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/Javascript">
    function fGetData() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "MyURL",
            data: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    USER_ID: "Username",
                    PASSWORD: "Mypassword",
                    QUERY_ID: 1234,
                    parameters: [
                        { key: "ORG_ID", values: ["1.32.10", "1.71"] },
                        { key: "term_dt", values: [""] }
                    ]),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/csv"
            },
            success: function (pData) {
                console.debug(pData);
            }
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="Results" value="Get Results" />
<br /> <br />
<div id="pData">
</div>
</body>
```

When executed properly, it's suppose to show data that's updated in real time on the HTML page where the DIV is after you hit the button "Results".

Comment: In your code where "url: "MyURL"", did you put an actual url, path, etc on your end? if so, please post the code of the page you are posting too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm running it in ASP.NET and have my Jquery source connected. Or
>   should I have the script in a seperate jquery file and link it to my
>   html?

You can directly reference the file in your page. You just have to make sure you reference jquery before you use any jquery function.

The 'url' parameter is your ajax call seems to be wrong, it is just a simple string. You have to put the url that has the POST method in your backend. (I'm assuming you didn't obfuscate the url)

In your question you say

> it's suppose to show data that's updated in real time on the HTML page
>   where the DIV is ...

But in your success function you only log the result of the ajax call (if the call is actually returning anything), when you probably want something like this:

```
success: function (pData) {
    // treat your result data here
    $('#pData').append(pData);
}
```

You can see an explanation of the method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp).